# JScript error __dopostback()

Tags: javascript, runtime, postback

I'm getting a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" on this line of code:

```
function ResetPanel()
    {__dopostback('pnlMaster', '');}
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function's name is `__doPostBack`, not `__dopostback`. Your capitalization is wrong.

Comment: I once took a class on case sensitivity, but apparently it did me no good. Thank you for your valuable post.